# Rust warp server issue when passing a handler with a generic

Tags: generics, rust, rust-warp

main.rs:

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use warp::Filter;

fn main() {
    //create http server

    let state = CState {
        inner: 2
    };

    Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async move {
        run_server(state.clone()).await;
    });
}

trait TaskType {
    fn create_task(id: Option<u64>, name: &str, time: u64) -> Self;
}

#[async_trait]
trait State<T: TaskType>: Clone {
    async fn add_task(&self, task: T) -> u64;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct CState {
    inner: u64,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct CTask {
    inner: u64,
}

impl TaskType for CTask {
    fn create_task(id: Option<u64>, name: &str, time: u64) -> Self {
        CTask{
            inner: 2
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T: TaskType> State<T> for CState {
    async fn add_task(&self, task: T) -> u64 {
        self.inner
    }
}


async fn run_server<T: TaskType, U: State<T>>(state: U) {
    let warp_state = warp::any().map(move || {
        state.clone()
    });
    async fn post_new_task_handler<T: TaskType, U: State<T>>(task_type_str: String, time: u64, state: U) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
        let task = T::create_task(None, task_type_str.as_str(), time);
        let id = state.add_task(task).await;
        Ok(warp::reply::json(&id))
    }
    let post_new_task_route = warp::post()
        .and(warp::path!(String / u64))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(warp_state.clone())
        .and_then(post_new_task_handler::<T, U>);
    let router = post_new_task_route;
    warp::serve(router).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "minimal_warp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
warp = "0.3"
async-trait = "0.1.68"
serde = "*"
serde_json = "*"
serde_derive = "*"
```

For the above code I get an error from the rust compiler which seems to indicate that I'm missing some trait bounds for the generic. However which bound I need to implement is not clear. If I write a non-generic version of the code it works. What's going on with warp here? What's the proper way to fix it and how would I diagnose such issues in the future?

To be clear I think it's not the route handlers that have an issue but more the closure where I pass in the state.

Also note I have an exact version of this code working with a concrete type instead of traits, so I know it's a problem with the traits.

The exact error message is shown below:

```
error[E0599]: the method `and_then` exists for struct `warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:65:10
   |
65 |         .and_then(post_new_task_handler::<T, U>);
   |          ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
  ::: /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/warp-0.3.5/src/filter/and.rs:13:1
   |
13 | pub struct And<T, U> {
   | --------------------
   | |
   | doesn't satisfy `_: warp::Filter`
   | doesn't satisfy `_: warp::filter::FilterBase`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>: warp::filter::FilterBase`
           which is required by `warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>: warp::Filter`
           `&warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>: warp::filter::FilterBase`
           which is required by `&warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>: warp::Filter`
           `&mut warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>: warp::filter::FilterBase`
           which is required by `&mut warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>, warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<warp::filter::and::And<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (String,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (u64,), Error = Rejection>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>>, impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Rejection>>, warp::filter::map::Map<impl warp::Filter + std::marker::Copy + warp::filter::FilterBase<Extract = (), Error = Infallible>, [closure@src/main.rs:53:38: 53:45]>>: warp::Filter`
```

Edit: This was changed to make the code a minimal running example.

Comment: A [mre] is needed for debugging quesitons on this site, see [ask].

Comment: @cafce25 all right I'll make one. I'll edit the question in a couple minutes. Edit: Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprinkling some `+ Send + Sync + 'static` seems to do the trick…

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use tokio::runtime::Runtime;
use warp::Filter;

fn main() {
    //create http server

    let state = CState { inner: 2 };

    Runtime::new().unwrap().block_on(async move {
        run_server::<CTask, CState>(state.clone()).await;
    });
}

trait TaskType {
    fn create_task(id: Option<u64>, name: &str, time: u64) -> Self;
}

#[async_trait]
trait State<T: TaskType>: Clone {
    async fn add_task(&self, task: T) -> u64;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct CState {
    inner: u64,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct CTask {
    inner: u64,
}

impl TaskType for CTask {
    fn create_task(id: Option<u64>, name: &str, time: u64) -> Self {
        CTask { inner: 2 }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl<T: TaskType + Send + 'static> State<T> for CState {
    async fn add_task(&self, task: T) -> u64 {
        self.inner
    }
}

async fn run_server<T: TaskType + Send + 'static, U: State<T> + Send + Sync + 'static>(state: U) {
    let warp_state = warp::any().map(move || state.clone());
    async fn post_new_task_handler<T: TaskType, U: State<T>>(
        task_type_str: String,
        time: u64,
        state: U,
    ) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
        let task = T::create_task(None, task_type_str.as_str(), time);
        let id = state.add_task(task).await;
        Ok(warp::reply::json(&id))
    }
    let post_new_task_route = warp::post()
        .and(warp::path!(String / u64))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(warp_state.clone())
        .and_then(post_new_task_handler::<T, U>);
    let router = post_new_task_route;
    warp::serve(router).run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3030)).await;
}
```

I can't explain why this works, the solution was found purely by trial and error:

- I did get a few error messages from your `#[async_trait] impl State for CState` related to `Send` and some lifetime `'async_trait` (so nothing to do with warp at all). Following the compiler error messages' suggestions there just led to more error messages. So the first "leap" of intuition was to add `T: Send + 'static`. The `Send` was suggested by rustc, but the `'static` is just based on "If you have trouble with lifetimes, first try `'_`, then try adding a parameter, then try `'static`." If that doesn't work, start thinking.
- From there on, `U: Send + Sync + 'static` was just complete guessing out of the blue, the warp-related error message is impossible to parse for humans. I did once remove the `U` parameter from `post_new_task_handler`, and then changed it to some benign type (`i32`) to make sure that `U` is really the problem. But then it was of the "Hmm. We just had problems with traits and futures and `Send`. Lemme just try…"
  The background knowledge here is that `async fn`-generated futures are state machines that save all parameters and variables at each `.await` (and at the start of the function). Oversimplifying, you can just think of `fn post_new_task_handler` as an

  ```rust
  enum PostTaskHandlerFuture<U, T> {
      Start { task_type_str: String, time: u64, state: U },
      AwaitAtLine2 { poll: /* type for U::add_task's future */ },
      Return { /* warp::reply::… */ },
      Finished
  }
  ```

  This state machine gets executed on `tokio` (mediated through warp's magic - the nice error messages are lost there), and for `tokio`'s work stealing scheduler  to be able to distribute work like executing `PostTaskHandlerFuture` over threads, `PostTaskHandlerFuture` needs to be `Send`. But for `PostTaskHandlerFuture` to be `Send`, `U` needs to be `Send`.  (I have no idea why `Sync` is necessary.)
  So this kind of "make some generic parameter `Send`/`Sync`" is a common thing when writing generic async code, hence I thought of trying it.

Comment: Can you explain how you knew what to do and why this works? Thanks!

Comment: I can explain, but not very well.

Comment: You can't explain what ChatGPT has given you? I flag this question because ChatGPT is prohibited

Comment: As a language model, I can neither deny nor confirm the claim that I may or may not actually be a human. (Also, this is an answer, not a question. :P)